# Measure maximum value of all prior date rows

Tags: mysql

I would like to add a column (maxPrice) that will measure the maximum value of another column (Price) for all prior Date rows. For example - table 1 has the following data:

```
     Date       Price   
......................
    12/19/2008  5
    12/18/2008  7
    12/17/2008  5
    12/16/2008  3
    12/15/2008  4
```

Would like output to be:

```
  Date     Price    MaxPrice
.................................
12/19/2008   5      7
12/18/2008   7      7
12/17/2008   5      5
12/16/2008   3      4
12/15/2008   4      4
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT
`Date`, Price, (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.Date < t1.Date) AS MaxPrice
FROM
yourTable t1
```